# VBA - autoupdate filter in excel after entering data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA and have been trying to get my spreadsheets to do a little more than just pivot tables allow.  I've been able to set up some autofilters in excel using VBA, but now I'd like to have the worksheet autofilter after I enter data into a cell.  However, neither of the two lines below work after I press enter.

Here are the two various lines of code I've tried:

## 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Target.Address = "$M$5" Then 
        Application.EnableEvents = False 
        FilterTo1Critera 
        Application.EnableEvents = True 
    End If 
End Sub
```

## 2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cel In Target
        Range("A3").Value = "Changed"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A")) Then Sheet1.Range("A").Value = 0
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Next cel
End If

End Sub
```

What's the correct approach to take?  Also, is there some good classes that I can take to brush up on some of these concepts??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *neither of the two lines below work after I press enter.* - are you placing them in the actual worksheet module, as opposed to a standard module? If not, do so and the event will fire. If they are in worksheet modules, we'll need a more clear description of how they do not work.

Comment: Ok...so this is how much of a noob I am.  I don't know how to set up a worksheet module over a standard module.  I've looked around through different sites to try and find the difference, and tried to insert modules into the worksheet in the VB application GUI, but there doesn't seem to be a distinction between the two.  Sorry, I realize that's extremely beginner, but I've tried to do some research on my own, but have failed miserably :-/

Comment: maybe this helps - it's pretty clear: http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html ... or this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/codemods.htm

Comment: Ok...so the first link is pretty great.  That cleared it up.  So when I put the first bit of code in, I get a 'Compile error: Sub or Function not defined error.  When I put the second line in, I get:  'Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range' as a warning and it highlights the 'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")' line of code.

Comment: Nm...I got it to work!  There was a dumb typo in Filterto1Criteria...an i was missing.  Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: If I want this to work across multiple cells, how would I have to modify the code?